# Metamask showing error but works from console

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

Hello I am trying to call my contract to deposit money to the contract. It works from the console, but it shows contract code error in metamask

**Web Metamask code**

```
let eth_amount = this.web3.utils.toWei( this.web3.utils.toBN('5'), "ether"); 
await this.token.methods.deposit().send({from:this.currentAddress, value:eth_amount});
```

**Contract Code**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

...
uint256 _totalSupply;
mapping(address => uint256) _playersDeposit;

function deposit() public payable {
    require(msg.sender.balance >= msg.value, "Balance is greater than value");
    require(msg.sender != _ownerAddress, "Requester is owner");

    _totalSupply += msg.value;
    _playersDeposit[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}
```

**This is what metamask shows**

[image]

//UPDATE :
Type of _totalSupply and _playersDeposit is added, in case that might be an issue

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Please help

//UPDATE
Tried in remix ide with web3, getting this error

[image]

Comment: Did you deploy it with the same wallet that you use in Metamask ?

Comment: I am still seeing the same error. I removed both require command. Can you please explain, what you mean by balance is superior to the amount?

Comment: Sorry, badly read.. Did you deploy the contract with the wallet that you use in Metamask ?

Comment: This is what i used to deploy the contract
0x5bA395EC0Ae0EA71a433A0EdcbD6f08eCf1794CA

This is what i am using to initiate the deposit
0x21d1A24D1dc593bc74355CA7556eE2d2Eac6572E

Comment: @AsifAlamgir The condition `require(msg.sender.balance >= msg.value` doesn't make much sense. Why are you comparing sender balance with the sent ether?

Comment: this was to make sure the user has enough fund to send the value. This is my first time writing a contract so i am not sure if metamask already validates this, added this in case it doesnt. Either way, i removed both require condition and it still showing the same error in metamask

Comment: Hi, did you end up figuring this out? Happy to investigate if not. I'd first try removing the two require statements and seeing if they are causing the issue. I'd also try changing the first line to "pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;".

Comment: @RyanShea unfortunately not. I will try with pragma solidity as you mentioned. One thing i have noticed in remix ide is this line // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0, 
I am not sure if this is required in a contract file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using wrong contract address when calling

```
new this.web3.eth.Contract(abiS, address);
```

Make sure the address is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in console, then the problem is likely in your implementation code. try adding a button that literally has the same code as your console code in the 'onclick'. then analyze your implementation code more closely.

your contract code (at least the part you've posted) is fine (I validated it on remix just to be sure). it is theoretically possible that other contract code could cause a problem, but again--if it works in the console, then your problem is either implementation or a bug in metamask itself (which is unlikely).